# Cronjob does not work, file not found even though it's located there

Tags: php, wordpress, cron

Hi I have a problem with Cron. I have a folder in root and inside I have a file to send emails, but I can't send email because there's an error "failed to open stream: file or directory not found: wp-load.php". But it is there in the root!  And so are the other files but they aren't found either. I've also tried using dirname(_FILE) and dir() instead of "../" but it's always saying not found. :S

```
require('../wp-load.php' );
require_once( '../wp-config.php' );
require_once( '../wp-includes/wp-db.php' );
require_once( '../wp-admin/admin-functions.php' );
```

Comment: is the file where this code you have posted also in the root?

Comment: try to use an absolute path to the resources, i.e `require_once('/var/www//wp-load.php')`

Comment: What does your cron command look like? Remember that cron will execute from the path you tell it, so your path within the file may not be what you think it will.

Comment: Gonna try that coderodour thanks

Comment: It should probably be `require_once('/var/www/vhosts/plazazero.com/wp-load.php')`  You'll have to adjust for exactly where `wp-load.php` is.

Comment: Same error, file not found. :/